# To start an animate function after finishing the other element (jQuery)

Tags: jquery-animate

I'm really afraid of asking questions here because anytime I have asked all attacks were on me but:

```
$("#button2").click(function(){
$("#button1").animate({width: "250px"}, 5000);
$("#button1").ready(function(){$("#div").animate({width: "400px"}, 5000);});        
});
```

Please help me, I want this: when I click on button2, it will animate div however I want to animate button1 and after finishing that, start animating div (NOT at same time).
Thanks and Appreciation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [.queue()](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) function:

```
$("#button2").click(function(){
   $("#button1").animate({width: "250px"}, 5000).queue(function() {
     $("#div").animate({width: "400px"}, 5000);   
     $(this).dequeue();
   });            
});
```